# How do I upload both images and form content in a vue？

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Upload images and form content? How to upload? The idea is to upload it to the client and then upload it to the server along with the form content, right?

I want to upload the form content and the image to the server when I click submit, instead of uploading the image separately when I upload the image. 
But I don't know how to upload at the same time. Can you help me?

```
<template>
   <form>
      <input type="text" v-model="test">
      <img :src="previewImage" class="uploading-image" />
      <input type="file" accept="image/jpeg" @change=uploadImage>
      <input type="submit"></input>
   </form>
</template>

export default {
  data(){
     return{
        previewImage:null,
        test: ''
     }
   },
   methods:{
            uploadImage(e){
                const image = e.target.files[0];
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(image);
                reader.onload = e =>{
                    this.previewImage = e.target.result;
                    console.log(this.previewImage);
                };

                const URL = 'http://xxxx'; 

                let data = new FormData();
                data.append('name', 'my-picture');
                data.append('file', event.target.files[0]); 

                let config = {
                  header : {
                    'Content-Type' : 'image/png'
                  }
                }
                axios.put(URL, data,config).then(response => {
                   console.log('image upload response > ', response)
                })
            }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to the form

```
<form @submit.prevent="uploadImage">
  <input type="text" v-model="test">
  <img :src="previewImage" class="uploading-image" />
  <input type="file" accept="image/jpeg" >
  <input type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you tell me why? I don't know what you mean. I want to upload an image and the contents of the form

Comment: With that you execute the uploadImage method only when you click in the submit button. And the prevent property is for preventing the page to reload

Comment: Yeah, but the image doesn't have data, and when you upload it to the server it doesn't have image data, right? Getting image data with FileReader? Assign previewImage?

Comment: You have 2 options, normally you need to transform your image data to base64 and save the encoded string, then when you read it, you decode it back or you upload it to an image server like firebase storage or cloudinary (which I recommend) and just save the url.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I don't know whether operation 1 is understood in this way. The image is converted into DataURL through FileReader object (it is already Base64). I'm going to do operation 2 in a second.